# Python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new in Selenium automation with Python. I was designing this hybrid framework for login. I get this error and don't know what the problem is.

```
def test_login(self):
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\91808\\Documents\\Chrome selenium package\\chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.get(self.baseurl)
        #import login action methods from page object file
        self.Lp=Logintest(self.driver)
        self.Lp.setUserName(self.username)
```

Error

> AttributeError: 'Logintest' object has no attribute 'setUserName'**

Code :

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't give code as image. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

You have the functions inside the init constructor like this:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.msg = "Hello World"
        
        def hello(self):
            print(self.msg)
```

Instead, declare your functions outside the init method like this:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.msg = "Hello World"
        
    def hello(self):
        print(self.msg)
```